# join 3 tables with 2 columns sql

Tags: sql, join

I want to do join between two tables on 2 columns, im getting error in clause where.

My query is below. 
Please if you can help don't hesitate.

Thank you,

```
select tab1.date, tab1.name, tab1.count1, tab2.count1 as count2, tab3.count1 as count3
from tab1 inner join tab2 inner join tab3
on tab1.date =  tab2.date
and tab1.date = tab3.date   
and tab1.name = tab2.name
and tab1.name = tab3.name
where tab1.date > '2013-01-01'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO , Please tag your database as well.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: SQL Error [42601]: Syntax error near « where » @AndyDan

Comment: @AndyDan do you see something ?

Comment: @monkey2 I believe VarunT has it in his answer now.  You need to provide the join condition for the first inner join before starting the second inner join.  You can't list all the joins then all the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing date and name columns in the query.

```
select tab1.date, tab1.name, tab1.count1, tab2.count1 as count2J
from tab1 
inner join tab2 
on tab1.date =  tab2.date and tab1.name = tab2.name
where tab1.date > '2013-01-01'
```

Edited*

```
select tab1.date, tab1.name, tab1.count1, tab2.count1 as count2, tab3.count1 as count3
from tab1 
inner join tab2 ON  tab1.date =  tab2.date
                AND tab1.name = tab2.name
inner join tab3 ON tab1.date = tab3.date   
               AND tab1.name = tab3.name
where tab1.date > '2013-01-01'
```

Comment: Thank you but was not that the prob . I posted all my code in the original post. Sorry :/